# Evento history.back() no funciona en mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, chrome

me gustaría aplicar la función windows.back() en una aplicación web para volver a la página anterior manteniendo los valores que tenía un formulario. En google chrome funciona correctamente, pero en mozilla firefox no funciona. ¿Existe algún metodo o alguna forma de realizar el mismo comportamiento en mozilla firefox?

Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo este esquema:

```
<li>
     <a href='javascript:window.history.back();' id='texto_regresar' name='Regresar' style="font-size:9px;">
      <center>
         <img src="imagenes/iconos/acciones/Regresar.png" width="50%" height="50%" title="REGRESAR"/>
      <br>PAGINA<br>ANTERIOR
      </center>
     </a>
</li>
```

me funciona tanto para Chrome como para Firefox, pero yo no tengo la necesidad de que permanezcan los datos en un formulario, la verdad no se si te funcione pero no pierdes nada con probar.

Comment: Si efectivamente, de esa forma, regreso a la pantalla anterior, pero en firefox no permanecen los valores de un formulario, cosa que si ocurre en Google chrome.

Comment: Quizás sea una pregunta tonta, pero por que ocupas regresar hacia atrás teniendo un formulario con datos ya capturados cual es el proposito o la necesidad de realizar ese paso ?.

Comment: Cuando yo relleno un formulario entero y doy a confirmar, tengo una pantalla siguiente con esos valores confirmados, pero si el usuario quiero regresar a la pantalla anterior por algún motivo, no debería rellenar los campos de nuevo como me ocurre ahora.

Comment: Si tienes razón, bueno podria mencionar este punto por que en una revision previa de un proyecto me lo mencionaron, actualmente estoy desarrollando con bootstrap y resulta que los formularios donde utilizas este esquema de que se vean bonitos y bla bla, pues los formularios se quedan con los datos, a mi me sucedio con con unos modales, que si los cierras y abres la informacion sigue ahi. Quizas podrias considerar a tu HTML agregar bootstrap y de manera "natural" se quedan los datos

Comment: Quizás no sea lo mas adecuado pero has intentado que por cada input del formulario tengas un campo input oculto donde almacenes ese dato, quizás podría ser útil.

Comment: y para que serviría ese input oculto? No te sigo...

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo este es parte de un codigo dentro de un modal, entonces en el modal se muestra cierta informacion, y en este caso en partircular tienes que añadir datos desde unos combobox select, pero para que estos datos se procesen correctamente necesitas indicar a la consulta de quien pertenecen, y quien estan en este momento trabajando con ese modal, entonces yo hago esto:

```html
<tbody>
 <tr>
 <td class="input-group-addon" style="font-size:10px;"><span><?=$nombre_EmpleadoResguardante?></span></td> // Este imprime el nombre del usuario dentro de una tabla 
 <td class="input-group-addon" style="font-size:10px;"><span><?=$numero_EmpleadoResguardante?></span></td> // Este imprime su numero de empleado en dentro de una tabla
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Numero_Empleado" name="Numero_Empleado" value="<?=$numero_EmpleadoResguardante?>">  // Este es para recuperarlo en un script para ser utilizado con Ajax
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="numero_EmpleadoMovimiento" name="numero_EmpleadoMovimiento" value="<?=$_SESSION['EMPLEADO_MOVIMIENTO']?>">// Este es para recuperarlo en script para ser utilizado con Ajax
</tbody>
```

Puedes observar que el primer input hidden trae un valor encerrado en esta forma `<?=$numero_EmpleadoResguardante?>`  este tipo de variables se traen desde una consulta, el otro valor lo traigo desde una variable de session... `<?=$_SESSION['EMPLEADO_MOVIMIENTO']?>`  y aquí se torna interesante por que acabo de encontrar una pagina donde te explican como puedes utilizar las variables de sesión para guardar datos y utilizarlos donde los requieras te dejo el link, mejor explicado no podría hacerlo yo.. [Guardar en una sesion los datos de un formulario en PHP](https://www.baulphp.com/guardar-en-una-sesion-los-datos-de-un-formulario-en-php/) Espero te sea de utilidad.

Saludos